# Как вывести картинку на сайт в asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Мне нужно вывести картинку на сайт. В Index.cshtml прописал следующий "код":

```
<img src="Images/1.jpg" alt="Image Error" />
```

На сайте в консоли выводит ошибку 404. Вопрос: Как собственно вывести картинку?

Comment: А какой путь при этом у картинки показывает - тот, где реально картинка лежит? У вас путь относительно текущей страницы.

Comment: GET https://localhost:7051/Images/1.jpg 404 - код ошибки

Comment: Хм, а кто у вас меняет `img` на `Images`, интересно. Это где-то прописано в конфигах?

Comment: Это я поменял, думал может он по умолчанию в папке Images ищет. Но нет, не пашет :)

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой проблемы достаточно переместить папку Images в папку wwwroot :)

Comment: [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0)